# how do I use offset method in VBA excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am writing VBA for Excel.  And I have a function that runs a subroutine from within.

```
Public Sub CalDailyHour(ByVal cIn As Range, ByVal cOut As Range)
   Dim TotalHour As Single
   If cIn.Value = "off" Then
      TotalHour = 0
   Else
      TotalHour = (cOut.Value - cIn.Value) * 24
   End If
   cOut.Offset(1,0).Value = TotalHour   <- This causes #Value Error
End Sub
```

and it will be called from following.

```
    Public Function CalDailyPay(ByVal cIn As Range, ByVal cOut As Range) As Single
      Dim DailyPay As Single
      If cIn.Value = "off" Then
          DailyPay = 0
      Else
          DailyPay = ((cOut.Value - cIn.Value) * 24) * 15
      End If

      CalDailyHour cIn, cOut  'Here, the sub above is called

      CalDailyPay = DailyPay
   End Function
```

Now when this sub is ran from another function, Offset causes #value error.  Why?  And what would be the solution for it?  Thanks in advance.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FPGcm.png)

Comment: What is the value of cOut - maybe you can post a screenshot of the sheet form which you "take" `cIn` and `cOut`

Comment: Both cIn and cOut have Time in form of ##:##.  However if an employee is off, then off is written.  That is why it is checking for value of cIn first.  Thanks.

Comment: I can't reproduce the error - did you check the value of `TotalHour` when debugging?

Comment: A `#VALUE!` error may appear when subtracting dates stored as text (or containing leading space) @stevie

Comment: When I delete omit Offset line, it works without error.  Both are running as "module"

Comment: I just added screenshot of problem.  Hope the picture will help.....  Thanks to all

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/description-of-limitations-of-custom-functions-in-excel-f2f0ce5d-8ea5-6ce7-fddc-79d36192b7a1#:~:text=A%20user-defined%20function%20called,Change%20another%20cell's%20value

Comment: UDF cannot modify cell values, only return a result (generally speaking, there are work arounds but usually best not to do this)

Comment: If you are using Excel365, you could rewrite your Function to Spill to the required number of (adjacent) cells